# Access "complex" object attributes from string in PHP

Tags: php

I have an object and need to access an attribute from a string like this:

```
$string = 'items[0]->sellers[0]->commertialOffer->Price';
```

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
$myObject->{$string};
```

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  I can't imagine any good reason for having a string like that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OOP (I removed the tag). Could it be, that you are actually  just  unaware of the **second parameter** in `json_decode()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$items = '{"items":[{"sellers":[{"commertialOffer":{"Price":33}}]}]}';
$myObject = json_decode($items);
$string = 'items[0]->sellers[0]->commertialOffer->Price';
echo ($myObject->{'items'}[0]->{'sellers'}[0]->{'commertialOffer'}->{'Price'});
echo ($myObject->items[0]->sellers[0]->commertialOffer->Price);
```

As `$myObject->items` is an array you can`t access it like

```
$string = 'items[0]';
echo $myObject->{$string};
```

You can access that by using

```
$string = 'items';
echo $myObject->{$string}[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the string between two functions ? If yes , then take 4 values and create the string like :-

```
$string = $value1.'|'.$value2.'|'.$value3.'|'.$value4 ;
```

Then explode the string and get back the 4 values .

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to revise your problem because interpreting raw code from a string is often a bad idea. You could potentially use the `eval` function: [see](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). Again, this is probably not a good idea: [when is eval evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)